# GreenPlum - Table With Trigger - Insert Failed

Tags: triggers, nested, greenplum

This is my first time using triggers in green plum environment. I think I have most of it setup but I am facing some issues when I insert data. Here is my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON leads.abhi_temp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE leads.my_trigger();
```

Here is the definition of the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION leads.my_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF ( NEW.date >= DATE '2003-01-01' AND
         NEW.date < DATE '2003-12-31' ) THEN
        INSERT INTO leads.abhi_temp_y2003 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSIF ( NEW.date >= DATE '2004-01-01' AND
         NEW.date < DATE '2004-12-31' ) THEN
        INSERT INTO leads.abhi_temp_y2004 VALUES (NEW.*);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now to insert data into my table I use

```
insert into leads.myData (select column1, column2 from leads.someOtherDara where column1 = '1');
```

But this gives me an error

```
ERROR:  function cannot execute on segment because it issues a non-SELECT statement (functions.c:133)
```

I think the error is because I am using nested queries to insert data. Not sure how to fix this. Any recommendation. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It might help if you showed the definition of `leads.my_trigger`.

Comment: Done. Added the information

Comment: The error message would suggest that Greenplum does not support DML (`insert`, `update`, `delete`) in triggers.

Comment: I guess makes sense. I have switched to rules instead

Answer (score 0):

I am aware, There is very limited support for triggers in Greenplum, It does not support DML operations.

May i know how do you achieve this, i mean how the rules can be applied as u said in your previous comments